# Loading secret FLV files from Amazon S3

Tags: php, amazon-s3, video-streaming, flv

I'm starting a new project that involves users paying to see educational videos. These videos (FLV) are hosted with Amazon S3 while the site itself is hosted on a regular web host.

I've tried to read up on securing the S3 files, and can't find any good solution for this. I don't want my users to download the videos directly.

I read something about setting up a HTTP streaming server, but I'm not quite sure how a service like this works, and how to set it up.

Anybody with any experiences on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't want my users to download the videos directly.

Get used to it.

Even with an RTMP streaming server, it's pretty easy to save the streams. You can add a load of obfuscation at the server and decoder to try to defeat the automated tools, but in the end what you have here is the unsolvable Copy Protection Problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to look at [s2Member](http://www.s2member.com/) for Wordpress - it has Amazon s3 protected files built in, with the time lapse thing, plus protected pages/ etc that you can setup pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to hide network path from end-user. However, you can go using expiring passwords that depend on time, user and content-section if Amazon allows you to use .htaccess files or PHP scripts.

Comment: That's the problem. They don't allow PHP nor .htaccess. So my best choice is to use the expiring key authentication method Amazon provides? The longest videos is at most 10 minutes long, how long access would you set?